# ROS maps generation from pdf files

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I have a blue print of my of my building in a pdf file. How can i generate a map from this pdf file so i can use it for navigation?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245199/ros-maps-generation-from-pdf-files/) by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2016-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you use the OccupancyGrid (according to the map_server node) in order to navigate the robot ,

you might need the map in PGM format and a description file in YAML ,with the data on the blueprint
transformed into a grid (in fact , an array)  which contains occupancy value.

=> You may convert the pdf into image file like bitmap and recreate the map by drawing things manually
(eg. wall , static obstacle , free area)

[Make sure that the resolution of the converted image is measured , it must be written in the description file.]

From image editing app like photoshop , you need to draw everything according to color definition .

[Black = Occupied , White = Free , Dark Grey = Unknown Area]

Map examples can be found easily on many repos as well as description file(YAML) ~ :D

---

Originally posted by [C3MX](https://answers.ros.org/users/25486/c3mx/) with karma: 150 on 2016-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on 2016-10-07**:
Thanks for the reply. I converted pdf file into a png format by taking a screenshot and tried loading it into rviz and stage. But i am having issues with dimensions i.e robots moves faster in stage than in rviz which is creating problem. do you have any idea how i can solve this?

**Comment by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on 2016-10-07**:
Also, if you have any tutorials on how to create maps using pdf files, can you point me in right direction?

**Comment by [C3MX](https://answers.ros.org/users/25486/c3mx/) on 2016-10-07**:
I'm not sure , it might be the resolution of the map .

**Comment by [C3MX](https://answers.ros.org/users/25486/c3mx/) on 2016-10-07**:
As far as I know ( 1-year experience ) , There is no way to do the conversion from PDF to PGM file at the moment.

**Comment by [C3MX](https://answers.ros.org/users/25486/c3mx/) on 2016-10-07**:
Implementation might be done by

Convert PDF to PNG  -> Define Scale size of the pixel cell compared to the real world -> Re-Paint Area (Wall , Free , Unknown) -> Export the image file and description file.

Some PDF to Image Library and OpenCV can achieve this , but it would be the hard way :(

**Comment by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) on 2016-10-07**:
Thanks, mate!